# How to get NET Core Authorization Working

Tags: .net, .net-core, razor-pages

I had an Authorization Policy wired up and working in .NET 2.2 Razor Pages app and then it just started giving me a 403 No access error. I am using Windows Authentication and Active Directory groups. I am part of the Admin group in Active directory. I added the Authorize tag to my page model and was able to access as expected. I swapped the tag out for the User group that i am not apart of and I no longer could access, which is expected. I then tried to give access to both Users and Admins at the same time and couldn't make it work. So i reverted back and now cant access with any group. What am i doing wrong here.

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireRole(@"DOMAIN\Admin");

                });
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("User", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireRole(@"DOMAIN\User");

                });
```

And here is the Authorize tag I am using:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
```

As i said, i am part of the admin group. And this worked about an hour ago and then just started giving 403. I removed my selft from the group and added back. I tried adding my self to the users group and then swapping out the authorize tag. I had problems earlier with a group that had a space in the name. i am not sure that was the problem, but the second i stopped usign that group is started working. am i battling something with AD not syncing to IIS Express in Visual Studio or something?

EDIT:

I tested changing the below which is another group i am apart of and it worked. It is not recognizing some groups for some reason. Though it recogized the Admin group at one point, it  doesnt now. 
'''
 policy.RequireRole(@"DOMAIN\Admin");
'''
to
'''
 policy.RequireRole(@"DOMAIN\APAdmin");
'''

Comment: AD information won't sync to IIS express . Please clarify which scenario make application suddenly return 403 ?

Comment: I am not sure, what is causing it. But i tested changing policy.RequireRole(@"DOMAIN\Admin"); to policy.RequireRole(@"DOMAIN\APAdmin"); which is another group i am part of in AD and it worked immediately. Its like it is not pulling back all groups I am apart of. THat's why I thought, maybe it is something to do with caching my AD groups.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with nested groups and IIS Express. It was not a problem in the live environment and would work with groups that were not nested.